# Cron Job with PHP5 CLI and ISP config

Tags: bash, symfony, cron

I am working on a project under Symfony2, and a dedicated server.
This server got ISP Config Panel.

I want that my cron runs a php-cli command line, integrated in symfony2 (php app/console config:renewalsession ).
My command in PHP-Symfony works really fine. If I run it manually, it does what I want.

But I am blocked with cron jobs. So I did a sh script, who calls the command.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/php5
php /var/www/clients/client1/web1/private/app/console config:renewalsession
```

I set up the cron job, for working in two minutes, I wait, and nothing happen.
I don't know from where it comes ...

So can someone help me ?

**Edit :**

I got some more informations. My sh script works fine. Problem was coming from how I filled inputs of the cron.

I have to fill a form with "minutes" "hours" "days of month" "months" "days of week" and my command. My command is good.
So the problem come from the rest of inputs.
I want that the cron runs everyday, one time, at 1h am.

So I have filled form this way :

- minutes : 0
- hours : 1
- days of month : *
- months : *
- days of week : *

What is wrong with those parameters ?

Comment: Why don't you just define your cron to run `/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/private/app/console config:renewalsession` ?

Comment: because ISP Config works this way : if you put a command, it runs command with sh, if you put url, it runs with wget.
From ISP config :
`Command to run (commands are executed via sh, urls via wget)`

Comment: Your values seems to be ok. Why this can't be ok in fact?

Comment: First : it doesn't work.
Second : the admin sys changes some value in this form, and it has worked. But he has put " * " everywhere except on month (he has put 1).
So, it works like this, but I dont want to run the cron every minute, every hour ...

Answer (score 0):

This will run your script at 1AM every day of the month:
0 1 * * * sh /path/to/script.sh